FirebaseCrashlytics onError Method Not Being Called in Flutter
Could someone help me with the proper configuration for FirebaseCrashlytics in Flutter?
The onLog and onException methods are being called, but the onError method is never called. I can't figure out how to configure it so that onError is triggered.
Here is my current setup:
await Firebase.initializeApp();

// Configuração do Crashlytics
await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
Talker talker = Talker(observer: CrashlitycsTalkerObserver(crashlytics: FirebaseCrashlytics.instance));
GetIt.I.registerSingleton<Talker>(talker);

I also have this
import 'package:firebase_crashlytics/firebase_crashlytics.dart';
import 'package:talker/talker.dart';

class CrashlitycsTalkerObserver  extends TalkerObserver {
  final FirebaseCrashlytics crashlytics;

  const CrashlitycsTalkerObserver({required this.crashlytics,});

  @override
  void onLog(TalkerDataInterface log) {    
    crashlytics.log(log.generateTextMessage());
  }

  
  @override
  void onError(TalkerError err) {
    crashlytics.recordError(
      err.error,
      err.stackTrace,
      reason: err.message,
    );
  }

  @override
  void onException(err) {
    crashlytics.recordError(
      err.exception,
      err.stackTrace,
      reason: err.message,
    );
  }
}


When you have a look into the source code of the package and search for the usage of onError it seems you need to use talker.handle from line 167 when working with observers:
https://github.com/Frezyx/talker/blob/85264b064b771d7cef4e26f024d2a59097e2fbf0/packages/talker/lib/src/talker.dart#L167
I was also stumbling on this and have to say it does not feel that intuitive.
